# visual studio community proxy

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, proxy, visual-studio-community

I am trying to use visual studio community behind a proxy, but I keep getting an error.

I have added the below to `D:\myVisualStudioInstall\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config`

```
    <system.net>
    <settings>
    <ipv6 enabled="false"/>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" enabled="true">
    <proxy bypassonlocal="true" proxyaddress="http://myProxy.com:8080" />
    </defaultProxy>
    </settings>
    </system.net>
```

And I get the error at start up:

> Unrecognized element 'defaultProxy'.
>   (C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\devenv.exe.config
>   line 1304)

Where have I gone wrong here? Everything I find online tells me that defaultProxy should be the name of this element, but maybe for the community edition there is some difference? I have already checked my credentials in the Windows Credentials Manager and it seems to work as IE isn't prompting me for them anymore.

Thanks

Comment: Remove the `settings` element, not sure where you got that bit from.

Comment: `settings` was already there. I have removed it and now visual studio won't launch at all.

but if i put it back in, it launches and gives me the familiar error

Comment: OK, I meant to put the `defaultProxy` element directly inside `system.net`, not in the `settings`

Comment: I moved the proxy stuff out from under settings, and that worked!!

can you add your comment as an answer so that i can mark it as the solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`defaultProxy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex(v=vs.110).aspx) element needs to sit directly under `system.net`, not inside `settings`. Move it there and it will work.

Comment: This worked. I now have 
        `<system.net>
        <settings>
        <ipv6 enabled="true"/>
        </settings>
        <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" enabled="true">
        <proxy bypassonlocal="true" proxyaddress="http://myproxy.com:8080" />
        </defaultProxy>
        </system.net>`

thanks again for your help!